# Java, Splitting an input file by colons

Tags: java, parsing, input, split

I want to split some Strings in java on the colon character.

The format of the strings are: `Account:Password`.

I want to separate the tokens: `Account` and `Password`. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I have a text file of USERNAME:PASSWORD , each Account/Password pair on its own line. I want to read the file line by line and put the username in its own variable and the password in its own variable.

Comment: `strLine.split(":")` should give you username and pass

Comment: Whats account and username? Both are different?

Comment: Yes. Both are different and I want each to go to their own variable, go to the next line, do the same, and repeat.

Comment: inside the loop: `namepass = strLine.split(":"); name = namepass[0]; pass = namepass[1]`, shouldn't this do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See Ernest Friedman-Hill's answer first.

```
String namepass[] = strLine.split(":"); 
String name = namepass[0]; 
String pass = namepass[1];
// do whatever you want with 'name' and 'pass'
```

Comment: Your answer helps alot! Would there be a way to make it read the first line of name:pass in a file, set those variables like above...then have it do some other tasks, THEN repeat the process, but with the next "name:pass" in the list?

Comment: Inside the loop in your code, extract name and pass this way and do whatever you want

Comment: Oh okay got it! Also, random. But do you know how to add to a JList?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what part you need help with, but note that the `split()` call in the above will never return anything other than a single-element array, since `readLine()`, by definition, stops when it sees a `\n` character. `split(":")`, on the other hand, ought to be very handy for you...

Comment: Changing it to split(":") just duplicates each entry in the list.

Comment: Changing it to `split(":")` would give you the username and password as two separate array elements, at which point you're free to do whatever you want with them -- that being the goal of the whole enterprise as I understood it.

Comment: Changing it to ":" just duplicates the entry in the list. So if I have 6 entries in my list, the output is 12 sets of "USERNAME:PASSWORD"

Comment: I cannot imagine what it is we're talking about -- but it looks like @mshsayem's answer worked for you, so all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use split(":"). Try this-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Account {
    String username;
    String password;

    public Account(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(.....){//read till the end of the file
            String input = //each line
            List<Account> accountsList = new ArrayList<Account>();
            String splitValues[] = input.split(":");
            Account account = new Account(splitValues[0], splitValues[1]);
            accountsList.add(account);  
        }
        //perform your operations with accountList
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That actually does get the ball rolling a bit! How would I put "sans" in one variable, and "pass" in another?

Comment: Go through edited answer. I haven't used getters and setters, still you can use them.