# Counting total Chars between two chars in a string - JAVA

Tags: java, string, char

Need help turning pseudo code into code.

The program would take in the input and print out if there is data occupied there.
So if there is nothing after the ":", it would fail. In this example, there is nothing after the reason, so that test would fail, all others pass.

I figured the best way to go about this is to just check for data after the colon to see if there is more then one char(the blank space) between the colon and the total length of text before the next colon. So the check from Reason to Status would be

```
//This would be the check betweek the reason colon and status colon - 6 chars //becuase of the word status
if(lengthBetween_ReasoncolonAndStatusColon - 6 > 2){
   //PASS
}else{
   //fail
}
```

**Format of Input**

```
User Name: Chris Smith ChrisSmith@gmail.com Users Password: 123ABC Last Login Date: 2015/10/14 - 12:30AM Reason: Status: Online
```

**Output**

```
Username: PASS
Password: PASS
Last Login: PASS
REASON: FAIL
Status: PASS
```

**Code**

```
//This would be the check betweek the username and password - 14 chars //becuase of the words User Password
if(lengthBetween_UsernameColonAndPasswordColon - 14 > 2){
   //PASS, there must be data here
}else{
   //fail, no data
}
```

Any help would do. A good starting point would be to show me how to could the total chars between two "key" elements. So I could use some help with code to say there is X amount of chars between the first two colon pairs, X amount between the next pair, and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use split() function to split your string by colon and put it in a list/array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004066/java-splitting-an-input-file-by-colons

Comment: I thought of this but this would truncate the info before the colon.

Comment: I guess if I accounted for the loss of chars this could work.

Comment: why would it truncate? I don't understand.

Comment: Well at first I dismissed it because it would split like so, String[1] = User Name String[2] = Chris Smith ChrisSmith@gmail.com Users Password string[3] = 123ABC .........Where User Password is apart of the split because it came before the colon, but if I expected that this works. I just subtract the expected chars that would be slit to each string. Thanks!

Comment: @yogidilip could you post an answer to this so i can accept your response as solving this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has lot of built in functions you can use:

- [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

  > Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.
- [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

  > Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character. If a character with value ch occurs in the character sequence represented by this String object, then the index (in Unicode code units) of the first such occurrence is returned.
- [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

  > Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
- [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

  > Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

## Play with them!!

---

If you feel you need a more powerful tool, please kindly check [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from [`APACHE COMMONS`](https://commons.apache.org/).

Comment: Split is the way to go. I'm giving that a shot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` method from `String` class in java

```
String s = "rtabcedaf";
int count = s.lastIndexOf('a') - s.indexOf('a') - 1;  //returns 4
```

Hope that's enough for you to start with.

Comment: Would this work for more then two instances of 'a'? This looks like it counts the first and last.

Comment: Cool, i'll take a look if things don't work with split(). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need:

```
String s = "User Name: Chris Smith ChrisSmith@gmail.com Users Password: 123ABC Last Login Date: 2015/10/14 - 12:30AM Reason: Status: Online";
int lengthBetweenReasonAndStatus = s.indexOf("Status:") - s.indexOf("Reason:");

if(lengthBetweenReasonAndStatus - 6 > 2) {
    System.out.println("Found");
}
```